# Javascript !undefined gives true?

Tags: javascript, undefined

When I try to alert a negation of variable having `undefined` value , I get the output as true?

```
alert(undefined);
alert(!undefined);
```

The first alert gives `undefined` and second alert gives `true`.
Is this the expected behavior. If so then why ?Am I missing some concept/theory about `undefined` in Javascript?

Comment: **Boolean NOT**. Revert the value, `undefined` is falsy value thus `!undefined` will give `true`.

Comment: What would you expect instead…?

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/ this might help

Comment: Conceptually… there are only two possibilities: Javascript throws an error when you try to treat a non-boolean value as boolean (`!undefined` → *error, use of non-boolean value in boolean context*); or the value will be coerced into a boolean, in which case `undefined == false` makes a lot of sense.

Comment: You just didn't think it through enough. Suppose var x is undefined accidentally. Then I write an if statement to check if x is undefined. if (!x) do something. !x returns true so that my if statement recognized it's undefined.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> Is this the expected behavior.

Yes.

> If so then why ?Am I missing some concept/theory about undefined in Javascript?

JavaScript has the concept of *implicit conversion* of values (aka *coercing values*). When you use the [negation ("NOT") operator (`!`)](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-logical-not-operator), the thing you're negating has to be a boolean, so it converts its argument to boolean if it's not boolean already. The rules for doing that are [defined by the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-toboolean): Basically, if the value is `undefined`, `null`, `""`, `0`, `0n`, or `NaN` (also `document.all` on browsers¹), it coerces to `false`; otherwise, it coerces to `true`.

So `!undefined` is `true` because `undefined` implicitly converts to `false`, and then `!` negates it.

Collectively, those values (and `false`) are called [*falsy* values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). Anything else¹ is called a [*truthy* value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). This concept comes into play a lot, not just with `!`, but with tests in `if`s and loops and the handling of the return value of callbacks for certain built-in functions like `Array.prototype.filter`, etc.

---

¹ *`document.all` on browsers is falsy, even though it's an object, and all (other) objects are truthy. If you're interested in the...interesting...history around that, check out Chapter 17 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Basically, it's to avoid sites unnecessarily using non-standard, out of date features.*

Comment: Great explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is the expected behavior.

Negation of the following values gives true in javaScript:

- false
- undefined
- null
- 0 (number zero)
- ""(empty string)

eg: !undefined = true

**Note:** The following checks return true when you == compare it with false, but their negations will return false.

- " "(space only).
- [ ](empty array),

eg: [ ] == false gives true, but ![ ] gives false

Comment: Empty arrays and space-only strings are not *falsey*.

Comment: [ ] == false will give true in console, I just checked, the same was tested for space.

Comment: Also check `![]` and `!" "` while you're at it…

Comment: @Samu: As for `[] == false`, it's because of Step 7 of the [Abstract Equality Comparison algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison). You end up comparing `0` with `0`.

Comment: Yep, just checked, you're right. " " == false gives true, but !" " gives false

Comment: Yup, `" " == false` ends up being `0 == 0` as well.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks :)  checked again and made edits.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's right. `undefined` is a *falsy* value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Falsy

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Answer (score 0):

If you need strict checks, you should avoid the non-strict operators:

```
$ node -p 'undefined == null'
true
```

and use the strict operators instead:

```
$ node -p 'undefined === null'
false
```

Unfortunately a strict negation does not exist.

But you can negate everything twice to get a true boolean equivalent:

```
$ node -p '!!undefined'
false
```